# the size parameter is always 0 when querying ElasticSearch from spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, elasticsearch

I'm trying to query elasticsearch with the elasticsearch-spark connector(5.3) but nothing returned

For example:

```
JavaRDD<String> esJsonRDD = JavaEsSpark.esJsonRDD(javaSparkContext, "global/target").values();
```

According the debug log, the size is set as 0.

```
17/04/21 14:58:31 DEBUG header: >> "GET /global/target/_search?size=0&preference=_shards:0 HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
```

Content can be fetched by accessing the url "/global/target/_search" via browser.
How to remove the size parameter in spark? I tried "es.batch.size.entries", it doesn't work.

Comment: Try `es.scroll.size` (default 50) and/or `es.scroll.limit` (default -1)?

Comment: Thanks. I changed both the "es.scroll.size" and "es.scroll.limit". It doesn't work either.

Comment: Have you tried esJsonRDD.take(10) after the query?

Comment: take() function doesn't work either. The size still is 0.